# Fetch Json values

Tags: php, json

The below result I am getting from some URL .
I am in need to fetch some values from the below json response in php

```
{"request":{"airport":{"requestedCode":"IXJ","fsCode":"IXJ"},"date":{"year":"2013","month":"4","day":"18","interpreted":"2013-04-18"},"hourOfDay":{"requested":"12","interpreted":12},"numHours":{"requested":"6","interpreted":6},"utc":{"requested":"false","interpreted":false},"codeType":{},"maxFlights":{"requested":"1","interpreted":1},"extendedOptions":{},"url":"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/json/airport/status/IXJ/dep/2013/04/18/12"},"appendix":{"airlines":[{"fs":"G8","iata":"G8","icao":"GOW","name":"GoAir","active":true}],"airports":[{"fs":"BOM","iata":"BOM","icao":"VABB","name":"Chhatrapati Shivaji International Airport","city":"Mumbai","cityCode":"BOM","countryCode":"IN","countryName":"India","regionName":"Asia","timeZoneRegionName":"Asia/Kolkata","localTime":"2013-04-18T08:37:27.791","utcOffsetHours":5.5,"latitude":19.095508,"longitude":72.874969,"elevationFeet":27,"classification":1,"active":true,"delayIndexUrl":"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/delayindex/rest/v1/json/airports/BOM?codeType=fs","weatherUrl":"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/weather/rest/v1/json/all/BOM?codeType=fs"},{"fs":"SXR","iata":"SXR","icao":"VISR","name":"Srinagar Airport","city":"Srinagar","cityCode":"SXR","countryCode":"IN","countryName":"India","regionName":"Asia","timeZoneRegionName":"Asia/Kolkata","localTime":"2013-04-18T08:37:27.791","utcOffsetHours":5.5,"latitude":34.002308,"longitude":74.762631,"elevationFeet":5436,"classification":4,"active":true,"delayIndexUrl":"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/delayindex/rest/v1/json/airports/SXR?codeType=fs","weatherUrl":"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/weather/rest/v1/json/all/SXR?codeType=fs"},{"fs":"IXJ","iata":"IXJ","icao":"VIJU","name":"Satwari Airport","city":"Jammu","cityCode":"IXJ","countryCode":"IN","countryName":"India","regionName":"Asia","timeZoneRegionName":"Asia/Kolkata","localTime":"2013-04-18T08:37:27.387","utcOffsetHours":5.5,"latitude":32.68077,"longitude":74.842824,"elevationFeet":1029,"classification":4,"active":true,"delayIndexUrl":"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/delayindex/rest/v1/json/airports/IXJ?codeType=fs","weatherUrl":"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/weather/rest/v1/json/all/IXJ?codeType=fs"}],"equipments":[{"iata":"320","name":"Airbus Industrie A320","turboProp":false,"jet":true,"widebody":false,"regional":false}]},"flightStatuses":[{"flightId":294315800,"carrierFsCode":"G8","flightNumber":"387","departureAirportFsCode":"IXJ","arrivalAirportFsCode":"BOM","departureDate":{"dateLocal":"2013-04-18T15:15:00.000","dateUtc":"2013-04-18T09:45:00.000Z"},"arrivalDate":{"dateLocal":"2013-04-18T18:05:00.000","dateUtc":"2013-04-18T12:35:00.000Z"},"status":"S","schedule":{"flightType":"J","serviceClasses":"RFJY","restrictions":"","uplines":[{"fsCode":"BOM","flightId":294284559},{"fsCode":"SXR","flightId":294354303}]},"operationalTimes":{"publishedDeparture":{"dateLocal":"2013-04-18T15:15:00.000","dateUtc":"2013-04-18T09:45:00.000Z"},"publishedArrival":{"dateLocal":"2013-04-18T18:05:00.000","dateUtc":"2013-04-18T12:35:00.000Z"},"scheduledGateDeparture":{"dateLocal":"2013-04-18T15:15:00.000","dateUtc":"2013-04-18T09:45:00.000Z"},"scheduledGateArrival":{"dateLocal":"2013-04-18T18:05:00.000","dateUtc":"2013-04-18T12:35:00.000Z"}},"flightDurations":{"scheduledBlockMinutes":170},"airportResources":{"arrivalTerminal":"1B"},"flightEquipment":{"scheduledEquipmentIataCode":"320"}}]}
```

Like I want to fetch only carrierFsCode,flightNumber,departureAirportFsCode,arrivalAirportFsCode,departureDate,arrivalDate,status,scheduledGateDeparture,flightDurations,flightDurations

There are many flight status in the json reponse.
Can some one please help me to get these values only.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON or you missed the starting and ending braces.  Just use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) function and it'll provide you data in associative array or as object.

Comment: Do you only want to get one `carrierFsCode` or one for each `flightStatus`?

Comment: @Explosion Pills Yes please I need these valus for every flight .

Comment: @Shilpu I have update the Json response now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have already tagged this with json-decode.. is there any particular reason that that isn't working for you?

```
$json = ''; //your json string here
$obj = json_decode($json);

var_dump($obj);
```

Edit:
Updating answer so as not to make the discussion extend for so long. In order to get all the statuses, you need to run a foreach loop for the flightStatuses array.

```
foreach ($obj->flightStatuses as $flightstatus) {
    echo $flightstatus->flightId,"<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have update the Json response in first post now. The code you gave I added in my PHP and pass URL to variable $json variable ,the output gives NULL. :(

Comment: @user2293208 I've updated the quotations in my answer. Since the JSON data uses double quotes, the variable assignment needs to use single quotes. I've just tested and it works. Please try again.

Comment: Thanks @antbird, it worked if I copy the response to the $json. But I have URL which give that reponse. How will I set the URL values to the same way as I copy the values .

Comment: @user2293208 Use `$json = file_get_contents($url);` instead of `$json='';` in that case.

Comment: :) Beautiful 
Now please tell me how can I fetch a particular value like flightId from this object for all flights.

Comment: @user2293208 Sure do have a lot of questions. :P `echo $obj->flightStatuses[0]->flightId;`

Comment: Hi It displyaed only one value of flight detail 
Here is the response from the URl
https://cdn.anonfiles.com/1366258934616.txt

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Thanks thanks alot.. I can see the vaues coming what I want . One last help . the other values are in other object like airportResources. How can I loop it also for that flight?
Sorry for troubling you so much .. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. You'd access it exactly like you would the flightId one: `$flightstatus->airportResources->arrivalTerminal;`. Additionally, if I've solved all your questions, I would very much appreciate you marking the answer above as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this JSON to an associative array using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Then, you can easily select the values you want. Assuming your JSON is contained in a variable called $data

```
$associative_array = json_decode($data, true);
$carrierFsCode = $associative_array['carrierFsCode'];
$flightNumber = $associative_array['flightNumber'];
```

... etc

Comment: NO :( not working .
I have api URL which give sthe json respone. I just need to echo the useful tags . I am not able to get it working .:(

Please see the qustion Data again I have just update the full response. I just need some of the values.

Comment: Also @Sam I have a URL . Icannot use the $json with data like that .
How will I use the URL to get the variables in $json

<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>